# Why 5 points determine a conic?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

How to prove that any five points, of which no 3 are colinear, that there is a single conic that passes through all of them?

(I have to start out with the equation $$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$ but I don't know what to do afterward.)

Comment: without loss of generality you can set $A=1$ - then using your 5 points you can generate 5 equations for the 5 unknowns B,C,D,E,F

Comment: @WW1 Yes, but the question is why those 5 linear equations in 5 unknowns have exactly one solution.

Comment: Maybe cramer's rule can help?

Answer (score 8):

Here's the outline of one method that uses some linear algebra.
$\def\Ker{\mathop{\mathrm{Ker}}}$

1. Consider the set of polynomials
   \begin{align}
   V = \{ Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F \mid A,\ldots,F\in\mathbf R \}
   \end{align}
   and show that this is a $6$-dimensional vector space.
2. Show that for two vectors $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ in $V\setminus\{0\}$, the conics defined by $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ are the same if, and only if, $f$ and $g$ are colinear.
3. For any point $P=(a,b)$ in the plane, consider the map $\varphi_P:V\to\mathbf R$ defined by $\varphi_P(f) = f(a,b)$ for any $f(x,y)\in V$. Show that it is a surjective linear map. From the surjectivity, deduce that
   \begin{align} \dim(\Ker\varphi_P) = 5. \end{align}
4. Show that a point $P$ is on the conic $f(x,y)=0$ if, and only if, $\varphi_P(f) = 0$.
5. Consider five points $P_1,\ldots,P_5$. Show that
   \begin{align} \dim\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^5 \Ker\varphi_{P_i}\right) = 1\end{align}
   if, and only if, no three of the points are colinear.
6. Conclude.