# Five points in $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ determine a curve $C\subseteq\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ of bidegree $(1, 2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

If $P_1,\ldots,P_5\in \mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ are five arbitrary points, how can I prove that there exists a curve $C\subseteq\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ of bidegree $(1, 2)$ such that $P_1,\ldots,P_5\in C$?

First of all, I think that if we denote the coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ as $\big( [x_0:x_1], [y_0: y_1]\big)$, then a curve $C\subseteq\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ has bidegree $(r, s)$ if $C$ is the projective zero set of a homogeneous polynomial $G=G(x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1)$ of degree $r+s$  such that $G$ is homogeneous of degree $r$ WRT $x_0, x_1$ and homogeneous of degree $s$ WRT to $y_0, y_1$ (lets say then that $G$ is bihomogeneous of bidegree $(r, s)$).

Now, I can't think of a feasible way of solving such problem. I was thinking about classical problems such as [Five points determine a conic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502799/why-5-point-determine-a-conic?rq=1) and [There is a cubic passing through 9 points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995531/projective-cubic-curve-passing-9-points), but I'm unable to use these techniques for this problem.  I also don't have much tools to tackle this (just basic algebraic geometry up to Bézout's theorem, not any fancy stuff about divisors, linear systems and that all).

Bonus: When can we say that $C$ is uniquely determined?

Regards

Comment: The same technique from the linked problems will apply here (with minor adjustments for the bihomogeneous case). Why do you say you're "unable to use these techniques"? What did you try?

Comment: I've actually made some mistakes, but now I see that if we write $G(x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1)=a x_0 y_0^2+b x_0 y_0 y_1+c x_0 y_1^2+ d x_1 y_0^2+e x_1 y_0 y_1 + f x_1 y_1^2 $, then we can find $a,\ldots,f$ such that $P_1,\ldots,P_5$ lies in $C=V(G)$. My issue is that this is a projective variety living in $\mathbb{P}^3$, not in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ (I want to say that it lies in the image of the Segre mapping, but I'm not sure how can I say that, nor that it's preimage in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ has the desired bidegree) [BTW, I haven't discussed the Segre mapping in class]

Comment: You might want to reread what you've written in your second paragraph, then - seems to me like you're done.